# Rsync backup one source directory and check agains multiple directories

Tags: bash, rsync

I am trying to copy(rsync) the "sdir" directory to tdir directories depending on what day it is. I want one full copy to mon directory, tues only what changed, wed only what changed, etc. but I am not getting the results I need.
Refer to actual command I ran:

```
[jesse@localhost test]$ tree
.
├── sdir
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
└── tdir
    ├── fri
    ├── mon
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    ├── thu
    ├── tue
    │   └── file3
    └── wed
        ├── file3
        ├── file4
        └── file5

7 directories, 11 files
[jesse@localhost test]$ touch sdir/file6
[jesse@localhost test]$ rsync -av --dry-run sdir/ --compare-dest=/home/jesse/test/tdir/mon/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/tue/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/wed/ /home/jesse/test/tdir//thu/ --backup-dir=/home/jesse/test/tdir/fri/
sending incremental file list
./
file3
file4
file5
file6

sent 294 bytes  received 31 bytes  650.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
[jesse@localhost test]$ rsync -av --dry-run sdir/ --compare-dest=/home/jesse/test/tdir/mon/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/tue/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/wed/ /home/jesse/test/tdir//thu/ --backup-dir=/home/jesse/test/tdir/thu/
sending incremental file list
./
file3
file4
file5
file6

sent 294 bytes  received 31 bytes  650.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
[jesse@localhost test]$ rsync -av --dry-run sdir/ --compare-dest=/home/jesse/test/tdir/mon/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/tue/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/wed/ --backup-dir=/home/jesse/test/tdir/thu/
sending incremental file list
./
file6

sent 208 bytes  received 22 bytes  460.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
[jesse@localhost test]$ rsync -av --dry-run sdir/ --compare-dest=/home/jesse/test/tdir/mon/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/tue/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/wed/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/thu/ --backup-dir=/home/jesse/test/tdir/thu/
sending incremental file list
./
file3
file4
file5
file6

sent 294 bytes  received 31 bytes  650.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
[jesse@localhost test]$ rsync -av  sdir/ --compare-dest=/home/jesse/test/tdir/mon/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/tue/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/wed/ /home/jesse/test/tdir/thu/ --backup-dir=/home/jesse/test/tdir/thu/
sending incremental file list
./
file3
file4
file5
file6

sent 438 bytes  received 95 bytes  1,066.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
[jesse@localhost test]$ tree
.
├── sdir
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
│   ├── file5
│   └── file6
└── tdir
    ├── fri
    ├── mon
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    ├── thu
    │   ├── file3
    │   ├── file4
    │   ├── file5
    │   └── file6
    ├── tue
    │   └── file3
    └── wed
        ├── file3
        ├── file4
        └── file5

7 directories, 16 files
[jesse@localhost test]$
```

Comment: Are you sure `--backup-dir` is the way you want to go? I'm a bigger believer in `--link-dest`, so that each backup is fully usable, with identical files hardlinked from the previous backup. That said, explore what you see with the `--itemize-changes` (`-i`) option. Might help you see what could be causing your comparisons to fail, if that's actually the problem.

Comment: Why do you ask if --backup-dir is the way to go? Is it bad...I did see inconsistent results with the backup switch when using --dry-run and without --dry-run. With --dry-run, it gives me correct files to update, but without --dry-run, it will copy everything that has changed since original backup.

Comment: rsync work fines when I run `rsync source mon` command. It also works, for `rsync source mon tue`, but not when I run `rsync source --compare-dest=mon tue wed`, this breaks and gives me everything that changed since monday, and put into wednesday. Using `--backup-dir` seems to give me the right result with `--dry-run` but when I run it without it, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note that the rsync man page clearly states that "*Beginning in version 2.6.4, multiple `--link-dest` directories may be provided*", and there's a similar note for `--compare-dest` but not for `--backup-dir` (which makes sense). If you want to restrict your backup to "only things that are not in one of a number of other directories", the `--*-dest` options are the way to go.

Here's my test and results:

```
$ mkdir src mon tue wed
$ for n in {1..3}; do date > src/file$n; sleep 1; done
$ rsync -avi src/ mon/
building file list ... done
.d..t.... ./
>f+++++++ file1
>f+++++++ file2
>f+++++++ file3

sent 346 bytes  received 92 bytes  876.00 bytes/sec
total size is 87  speedup is 0.20
$ for n in {4..5}; do date > src/file$n; sleep 1; done
$ rsync -avi --compare-dest=$PWD/mon/ src/ tue/
building file list ... done
.d..t.... ./
>f+++++++ file4
>f+++++++ file5

sent 295 bytes  received 70 bytes  730.00 bytes/sec
total size is 145  speedup is 0.40
$ for n in {6..7}; do date > src/file$n; sleep 1; done
$ rsync -avi --compare-dest=$PWD/mon/ --compare-dest=$PWD/tue/ src/ wed/
building file list ... done
.d..t.... ./
>f+++++++ file6
>f+++++++ file7

sent 319 bytes  received 70 bytes  778.00 bytes/sec
total size is 203  speedup is 0.52
$
```

The notable difference here is that **each** of the compare directories needs its own option. The notation is not:

```
rsync --compare-dest one/ two/ src/ dest/
```

but rather:

```
rsync --compare-dest=one/ --compare-dest=two/ src/ dest/
```

To put this into code that gets run each day, you might try something like the following (untested script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Store our rsync arguments in an array, for easier handling.
rsync_args=(-a)

# If we're running interactively, show us rsync verbose output.
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  rsync_args+=(-vi)
fi

# Step through weekdays, adding days to our argument list, stopping at "today"
read today < <(date '+%a')
for day in Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri; do
  [ "$day" = "$today" ] && break
  rsync_args+=(--compare-dest=$PWD/${day,,})
done

# And finally, copy everything.
rsync "${rsync_args[@]}" src/ "${day,,}"/
```

Note that bash's case control in parameter expansion (`${s,,}` and `${s^^}`) are features of bash version 4.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to do. You are a genius sir. One more question. I noticed that directories that have not changed are copied to destination with no files, which makes sense, but is there a way to prevent the directory name from getting created at the destination.

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answer appears to solve things for you, please feel free to mark the question as closed by clicking the check-mark to the left of the answer. :-)  As for skipping empty directories, I see from rsync's man page that there's a `--prune-empty-dirs` option which you could experiment with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did see that option but the directories that I want rsync to skip are the directories that are up-to-date and have nothing to be updated. In other words, I want to avoid the entire hierarchy from being created if only one file changed in one directory. I only want those directories that contain the file to be created on the destination. Is this a new question I should be posting on stackoverflow?

Comment: Hmm. So you want `--compare-dest` to skip unchanged directories, rather than creating the directory hierarchy on the target? I'm not sure that's possible, as I think `--compare-dest` only acts on *files*, but I'm also not sure that I'm understanding this 100%, which makes me think that [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be in order, which probably means a new question. It's also possible that this sort of thing might be a candidate for [StackOverflow Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation).

Comment: Yes, I only want directories that contain updated files to back up to destination. If I have on source: dir1/d1file1  and dir2/d2file1.....now I modify/update contents on dir1/d1file1....Now I rsync, I want only dir1/d1file1 on the destination...but I am getting  dir1/d1file1 and dir2(but it is empty, which it should be, this is what I want to prevent, this directory should not be on the destination). I'll post new question.